# Complicated venn diagram!

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to work out the following Venn diagram question for the past 3 hours and I have not been able to work it out.

The main reason why I am struggling is because I dont have the value for the centre circle.

> [image: Venn Diagram problem]

Please can someone provide input on how to solve the question.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint...put $x$ in the centre region, then work outwards filling each region with the amount in terms of $x$, so that, for example, $$n(B\cap M\cap L')=11-x$$

Answer (score 3):

A venn diagram can help keep track of information in a visual format for three or fewer sets, but if and when you are asked to complete a similar problem where there are *four* or more sets, venn diagrams can become far too complicated or even impossible to draw on paper.  For that reason, I suggest looking at a purely pen-and-paper approach that doesn't use such a diagram which doesn't have the same limitations.

Let $B$ represent the set of students with a bike, $P$ who have a phone, and $C$ who have a computer.  Let $\Omega$ represent the set of all students in the class.

We are told the following information:

- The total number of students is $|\Omega|=32$
- The number of students who have a bike (*among possibly other items*) is $|B|=19$
- The number of students who have a phone (*among possibly other items*) is $|P|=21$
- The number of students who have a computer (*among possibly other items*) is $|C|=16$
- The number of students who have a bike and a phone (*among possibly other items*) is $|B\cap P|=11$
- The number of students who have a phone and a computer (*among possibly other items*) is $|P\cap C|=12$
- The number of students who have a bike and a computer (*among possibly other items*) is $|B\cap C|=6$
- The number of students who don't have any of the mentioned items is $|\Omega\setminus(B\cup P\cup C)|=2$

From the final piece of information, we learn that the number of students with at least one of the mentioned items is $|B\cup P\cup C|=|\Omega|-|\Omega\setminus(B\cup P\cup C)|=32-2=30$

Now... applying inclusion-exclusion principle, we know that

$$|B\cup P\cup C|=|B|+|P|+|C|-|B\cap P|-|B\cap C|-|P\cap C|+|B\cap P\cap C|$$

We know all of these pieces of information except the final one, $|B\cap P\cap C|$, the number of students who have all of a phone, bike, and computer, and this is precisely the number we are asked to calculate in the problem, so by plugging in the appropriate numbers we can find it.

---

It is unclear exactly how you got stuck since you did not share any of your own efforts, but a common mistake would be that you interpreted certain phrases incorrectly.  For example, the phrase "11 students have both a phone and a bike" means that these eleven students have a phone and a bike *and some of them might have a computer too*.  I have seen several people assume that the $11$ students being referred to must all not have a computer and that any students with a phone, bike, *and* computer must be referred to elsewhere separately and aren't counted within those $11$ mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C$ denote the events that someone has a bike, phone, and laptop, respectively.

For $(a)$ you can use the fact that $$P(A\cup\ B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A \cap C) - P(B \cap C) +P(A \cap B \cap C)$$

where $$P(A\cup\ B\cup C)=1-\frac{2}{32}$$

For $(b)$ note that

$$\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B \cap C \mid (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B\cap C))
&=\frac{P((A\cap B \cap C) \cap ((A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B\cap C)))}{P((A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B\cap C))}\\\\
&=\frac{P((A\cap B \cap C)}{P((A\cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cup (B\cap C))}\\\\
\end{align*}$$